# Unable to run babel-node via shell command

Tags: node.js, babeljs, babel-node

I am trying to use `babel-node` to run files in my `node` project.

I am able to get them running if I set up an `npm script`, such as:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node src/index.js"
  },
```

However, if I try to run it via the cli, I get the error: `zsh: command not found: babel-node`.

I've already tried installing `babel-node` both globally, and as a dev-dependency, via:

`npm i -g @babel/node @babel/cli`

But this hasn't worked for me.

Does anyone know why the shell command doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

per https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-node

> Compile and run test.js.
>
> Shell
>
> npx babel-node test

so you should update your script to

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "npx babel-node src/index.js"
  },
```

And you should be able to lose the `/index.js` part, simplifying to

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "npx babel-node src"
  },
```

Comment: Thanks, `npx babel-node src` works. But why do we use `npx` if I have installed the package to my `node_modules`? I figure I should be able to run it with something like `babel-node <filename>`.

Comment: You can learn more about `npx` here, https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx, but basically node-babel is not in your path and `npm` has updated how they look for binaries, which necessitates the need to use `npx`

Comment: Thanks, I marked your answer and appreciate all the extra info. One last question, in my script, I'm able to use `"start": "babel-node <file>"` as opposed to `"start": "npx babel-node <file>"`, why is this? Since I cannot use `babel-node` in the CLI.

Comment: I can't find the exact documentation off hand, but `npm` auto prefixes it's scripts with `npx` when it's not present. I honestly misread your question at first and was really surprised it was needed and was trying to reproduce, but that's what I get for not reading well :P